# android getRunningAppProcesses always returning null

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, touch-event

I have :-

```
Class Abc extends Activity(){

 private ActivityManager am;
 private List<RunningAppProcessInfo> rList;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
      }

     @Override
     public void onStart (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onStart(savedInstanceState);        
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        super.onTouchEvent(event);

        rList= am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        Log.e("MAIN", rList.isEmpty() +" .");

        return true;
     }
}
```

`am.getRunningAppProcesses()` is always `null` even though i have foreground apps running, the active applications also shows them correctly. i know that its supposed to return `null` if there's nothing else running, but i launch other apps (gmail, camera, for testing)

Is this a permissions issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out.
For `ActivityManager am`, since the constructor is `private`, and no `static` instances are available, it must be instantiated like:

`am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);`

Hope this is useful to someone stuck with a similar problem